# How to import an mcedit schematic using world edit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit, mcedit

I made a very awesome mob arena that I want to put on a friend's server. We've tried using world edit to import it but it doesn't paste in the right location. Most of the arena is underground and the whole thing appears above ground when you paste it. He said that mcedit and world edit copy differently, so I tried copying it with world edit in single player. I pasted it to see if it would work, but all of the signs pasted empty and all of the special properties on the spawner didn't copy either.

Is there a way to import it onto the smp server using world edit? Does world edit on servers actually copy everything?

Comment: Why not just use MCEdit?  It seems to me you're just over-complicating things by not doing that.  Yes, you have to take the server offline, but it's worth it in order to do the job right.

Comment: Problem is that the server owner refuses to use it or let me use it for him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry, there's no way to do this unless you talk to sk89q, the developer. Your friend is right, WorldEdit and MCEdit copy differently, and custom data is lost.

Comment: From the research I've done on the forums, they use the same schematic format.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes, they use the same schematic format but WorldEdit doesn't copy over the tile data, like MCEdit does.

Comment: So WorldEdit doesn't copy metadata such as sign text or block facing? That does seem to be a failure to provide a complete feature.

Comment: Well, there's two different levels of data attatched to a block. One is only copied by MCedit, while the second is copied by both. I don't know the difference, or what they're called.

Comment: You might mean metadata and NBT tags. I'm still surprised that's not copied, since nearly everything in Minecraft is moving to using NBT for anything more complicated than block facing. If WorldEdit can't handle NBT data, it will quickly become obsolete.

Comment: I'd like to go and test, but I can't seem to get WE for single player. can you give me an example of what blocks/items have what metadata?